# Responsive navbar bootstrap not working in centralized page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little problem using responsive navbar. I have two divs that centralize my page.

```
<div id="tudo">
    <div id="conteudo">
        <!--My content here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#tudo
{
    width: 876px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left; /*hack for IE*/
}
#conteudo
{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

But when I copy the code for responsive the layout does not work -> [Here](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-4ElloQ2g2_E/UaP7EUunIOI/AAAAAAAAAD0/OfUNTiwRJT8/s1600/leiaute.jpg)

Comment: The best option would be if you could create a jsfiddle with your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your CSS is setting `#tudo` to a fixed width of `876px` which doesn't allow the navbar to be responsive.

The easiest solution would be to use a @media query to set the width of the #tudo to `auto` when the responsive navbar kicks in at `979px`

```
#tudo
{
    width: 876px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left; /*hack for IE*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
#conteudo
{
    padding: 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

@media (max-width: 979px) {

  #tudo {
      width: auto; 
    margin: 0;
  }
  #conteudo {
      width: auto;
  }

}
```

<kbd>[**Demo on Bootply**](http://bootply.com/62403)</kbd>

Comment: This solves my problem. What the name of that declaration @media, I don't know the usage.

Comment: Here is more info on @media queries- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045893/which-are-the-most-important-media-queries-to-use-in-creating-mobile-responsive