# How to make my HTML suitable for Mobile View

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

How to make my HTML suitable for Mobile View (responsive UI)

I've coppied 3 packages ( Price labels ) source code from http://cssdeck.com/labs/pricingtables, and when I embed CSS and HTML code to my website the page view works fine using my PC (Desktop) but when I use my Phone(Android) not all of packages appear, Can you please help?

[My website](http://richmindedbranding.com/project-starter/)

Comment: It is called as Responsive UI for cross device alignments. Please refer bootstrap library and Jquery mobile UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the following code snippet. Since it makes use of basic elements of bootstrap functionality.You can check the UI responsiveness on across different mobile devices.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <!--Added class row -->
        <div class="page-container row">
            <!---Added col-lg-4 class -->
           <!-- Total 12 columns are divided into 3 parts as col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="pricing-table col-lg-4">
                <div class="pricing-table-header">
                    <h2>Personal Site</h2>
                    <h3>$15/month</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="pricing-table-space"></div>
                <div class="pricing-table-features">
                    <p><strong>50</strong> Email Addresses</p>
                    <p><strong>35GB</strong> of Storage</p>
                    <p><strong>40</strong> Databases</p>
                    <p><strong>10</strong> Domains</p>
                    <p><strong>24/7 Unlimited</strong> Support</p>
                </div>
                <div class="pricing-table-sign-up">
                  <p><a href="http://bloggingbolt.blogspot.com">Sign Up Now</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pricing-table pricing-table-highlighted col-lg-4">
                <div class="pricing-table-header">
                    <h2>Small Business</h2>
                    <h3>$59/month</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="pricing-table-space"></div>
                <div class="pricing-table-text">
                    <p><strong>This is a perfect choice for small businesses and startups.</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="pricing-table-features">
                    <p><strong>Unlimited</strong> Email Addresses</p>
                    <p><strong>65GB</strong> of Storage</p>
                    <p><strong>75</strong> Databases</p>
                    <p><strong>25</strong> Domains</p>
                    <p><strong>24/7 Unlimited</strong> Support</p>
                </div>
                <div class="pricing-table-sign-up">
                    <p><a href="http://bloggingbolt.blogspot.com">Sign Up Now</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pricing-table col-lg-4">
                <div class="pricing-table-header">
                    <h2>Corporate Site</h2>
                    <h3>$85/month</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="pricing-table-space"></div>
                <div class="pricing-table-features">
                    <p><strong>Unlimited</strong> Email Addresses</p>
                    <p><strong>85GB</strong> of Storage</p>
                    <p><strong>Unlimited</strong> Databases</p>
                    <p><strong>50</strong> Domains</p>
                    <p><strong>24/7 Unlimited</strong> Support</p>
                </div>
                <div class="pricing-table-sign-up">
                    <p><a href="http://bloggingbolt.blogspot.com">Sign Up Now</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Refer the use of different components of bootstrap as http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: Thank you it works but when i embed this code the previous css design disappear how can i customize this code only for packages plz not for the whole website

Comment: Please customize you css according to bootstrap classes.

Comment: @Daenarys Awesomeness of bootstrap. :)

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `<head>` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: i've added the code on <head> tag but same result see http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/?u=http://richmindedbranding.com/project-starter

Comment: Edit the `margin` in the css to `margin: 0%;`

Comment: added nothing changed :/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your head tag:

It you are using Twitter Bootstrap, add this class to you main/wrapper div:

```
<div id="Wrapper" class="container">
```

Otherwise look up some info on css media queries and add them to your style sheet.

EDIT:
Since you are using WP locate your functions.php and add the files;

```
function my_scripts_enqueue() {
wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );
wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );


wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_enqueue' );
```

As for media queries, have a look at this post;

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045893/which-are-the-most-important-media-queries-to-use-in-creating-mobile-responsive
```

hope that helps

Comment: Can you do it for me plz? i mean heres the source code for the page:

richmindedbranding.com/project-starter/index.htm view source code plz

Comment: Hi @KeithZetterstrom i have updated my answer... your '<div class="page-container">' should become '<div class="container">'