# Responsive web site, CSS width of types

Tags: css, web

I want to make my website responsive in phone ... etc

My questions is I want to know the width that I make it in @media (CSS) to any type

for example phone I make 768px that's right ?

I need your help :'(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which are the most important media queries to use in creating mobile responsive design?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045893/which-are-the-most-important-media-queries-to-use-in-creating-mobile-responsive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the sizes that Twitter Bootstrap uses for their responsive layout.

```
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```