# Are my media queries correct

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

I was wondering if someone could tell me if my media queries look correct.
I'm completely new to web design and I'm doing a course.  I have to make my website responsive and submit it tonight but I'm really struggling.  I have spent hours researching and changing things but for some reason, my queries don't seem to work for some things.

These are the ones I've done so far

```
/*media queries*/

/*768px*/




@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)and(max-width:1024){
.tm-logo{   
align-items: center;}    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)and(max-width:1024){
.tm-nav ul li a{
padding: 20px 30px;
text-decoration: none;}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)and(max-width:1024){
.tm-nav ul li{
display: inline-block;
background-color: #80c625;
padding: 10px;
}
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)and(max-width:1024){
.divTableBody {
padding: 5px;
align-content: center;}
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)and(max-width:1024){
.more{align-items: center;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)and(max-width:1024){ 
.wish{width:100%;
float:none;
align-items: center;}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)and(max-width:1024){
    .whybody img{
        float: none;
        align-items: center;}
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)and(max-width:1024){
.why-logo{ text-align: center;
    }

    }
/******480px*****/

@media only screen and (min-width:320px)and(max-width:480px){
    .wish{width:100%;
    float:none;
    align-items: center;}
}


@media only screen and (min-width:320px)and(max-width:480px){

.tm-logo{
       align-items: center;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width:320px)and(max-width:480px){
.tm-nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
     background-color: #80c625;
    padding: 10px;
    align-content: center;
    }
}

 @media only screen and (min-width:320px)and(max-width:480px){   
.divTableBody {
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5%;}
}


@media only screen and (min-width:320px)and(max-width:480px){
.more{
    align-items: center;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width:320px)and(max-width:480px){
    .whybody img{
        align-items: center;
    float: none;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width:320px)and(max-width:480px){
.why-logo{ text-align: center;
    }

    }

/********footer*******/
@media (max-width: 600px) {

    .footer-distributed .footer-left,
    .footer-distributed .footer-right{
        text-align: center;
    }

.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-left p.footer-links{
    line-height: 1.8;
}
}
```

This is my CSS:

```
    /*default page style*/


    body{
    display: block;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5%;}


    h1{color: #39a3c3;
    font-size: 3em;}


    h2{color: dimgray;
    font-size: 2em;}


    h3{color:#80c625;
    font-size: 1em;}


    p{font-size: 1em;}

    /* NAVIGATION STYLE */


    .tm-container{
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;

    }  

    .tm-header{
     background: #fff;
     }

    .tm-header::after{
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    visibility: none;
    }

    .tm-logo{
    float:left;
    }

    .tm-nav{
    float:right;
    font-size: 20px;

    }


    .tm-nav ul li{
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: #80c625;



    }

    .tm-nav ul li a{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 60px;



    }
    .tm-nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #ffea25;
    background-color: #80c625;  
    }

    /**********************navigation style finish**********************/
    .rightimg{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1em;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;  

    }
    /*****************start of What We Do styles***************************/

    /* DivTable.com */
    .divTable{
    display: table;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    float:left;
    clear:none;

     }

    .divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
    max-width: 100%;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
     max-width: 100%;


    }

    .divTableCell, .divTableHead {
    border: 0.2em solid #ffffff;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
     max-width: 100%;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
     max-width: 100%;
    }
    .divTableFoot {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-footer-group;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
     max-width: 100%;
    }


    .rightimg{
    clear:both;
    }

    /****************************More Button***************************/

    .more {
    background-color:#2fa1c4;
    -moz-border-radius:8em;
    -webkit-border-radius:8em;
    border-radius:6em;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:90%;
    padding:8% 10%;
    text-decoration:none;
    align-items: center;

    }


    .more:hover {
    background-color:#80c625;
    }
    .more:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    }



    .image-table {clear: both}

    /****************end of What We Do styles************/
    .wish{
    float: right;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    clear: both;
    }




    /*******************start of Why Choose Us section**************/
    .whybody {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;



    }
    .whybody img{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1em;
    max-width: 100%;


    }

    .why-logo{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    }

    .textlist {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style-image: url('images/bluedot.png');
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;


    }

    .textlist ul li {
    word-wrap: normal;
    padding-right: 1em;
    }

    /****************end of Why Choose Us section******************/

    /******************Brands section*******************/



    .flexbox-header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;



    }

    .flexbox-item {

   background: #ffffff;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   max-width: 100%;

    }

    .flexbox-item img{
    width: 100%;

    }



    /*****start of footer*****/

    .footer-distributed{
    background-color: #80c625;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal 16px sans-serif;

    padding: 45px 50px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-left p{
    color:  #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    }

    /* Footer links */

    .footer-distributed p.footer-links{
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    }

    .footer-distributed p.footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-right{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 6px;
    max-width: 180px;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-right a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color:  #ffffff;
    border-radius: 2px;

    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;

    margin-left: 3px;
    }
```

Honestly, I could have just made complete balls up and I understand if I should just redo most of it from scratch but I have to at least submit something by this evening. Hopefully someone can assist me!
Thanks!

Comment: Hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045893/which-are-the-most-important-media-queries-to-use-in-creating-mobile-responsive

Comment: you forgot to add 'px' after 1024 at your first queries

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using media queries you can stack up all your code that you want for different screen sizes and use them together like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px) {
   .tm-logo{   
      align-items: center;
   } 

   .tm-nav ul li a{
      padding: 20px 30px;
      text-decoration: none;
   }

   .tm-nav ul li{
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #80c625;
      padding: 10px;
   }

   .divTableBody {
      padding: 5px;
      align-content: center;
   }

   .more {
      align-items: center;
   }

   .wish {
      width:100%;
      float:none;
      align-items: center;
   }

   .whybody img{
      float: none;
      align-items: center;
   }

   .why-logo { 
      text-align: center;
    }
}
```

This is for your first query, you can do the same with the other 2 queries you have.

Comment: I think your comment to the question should be the actual answer, but this is equally useful as a tip regarding css formatting!

Comment: thanks!  I  adjusted it like you said.  But with regards to the 768px and 1024px it still doesn't make my images and things center, which I thought I'd done in the code.

Comment: I added this to my HTML...I uploaded the file mq.css to filezilla...maybe I added thta wrong?   <link href="mq.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  It looks fine to me but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px)and(max-width:1024px) {
  .tm-logo {
    align-items: center;
  }
  .tm-nav ul li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .tm-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #80c625;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .divTableBody {
    padding: 5px;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .more {
    align-items: center;
  }
  .wish {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .whybody img {
    float: none;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .why-logo {
    text-align: center;
  }
  /******480px*****/
  @media only screen and (min-width:320px)and(max-width:480px) {
    .wish {
      width: 100%;
      float: none;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .tm-logo {
      align-items: center;
    }
    .tm-nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #80c625;
      padding: 10px;
      align-content: center;
    }
    .divTableBody {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 5%;
    }
    .more {
      align-items: center;
    }
    .whybody img {
      align-items: center;
      float: none;
    }
    .why-logo {
      text-align: center;
    }
    /********footer*******/
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .footer-distributed .footer-left,
      .footer-distributed .footer-right {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .footer-distributed .footer-right {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
      }
      .footer-distributed .footer-left p.footer-links {
        line-height: 1.8;
      }
    }
```

You can do this.Measuring width is a nice practical example of media queries, but it isn't the only thing available. You haven't mentioned the **px** after 1024  and there is no need to redeclare **@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)and(max-width:1024px)** again and again :)